# How to call method from another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller class `ViewController` with collectionView. Also I have singleton class `FacebookManager` for fetching data from facebook.

What I want to do is to run a method in facebook class and then call a method in ViewController to reload collectionView.

I tried to make a reference to ViewController in Facebook manager by setting

```
class FacebookManager  {
   static let sharedInstance = FacebookManager()
   var vc:ViewController?
}
```

Then setting in ViewController

```
class ViewController: {
   func viewDidLoad() {
      FacebookManager.sharedInstance.vc = self
   }
}
```

And then calling in FacebookManager

```
func myMethod() {
   vc.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

But this doesn't work.

How to do this properly?

Comment: Since `FacebookManager` is a singleton and is accessible from everywhere, call the method to fetch data from the controller which contains the collection view.

Comment: Yes, but how then to call ViewController from FacebookManager back ?

Comment: Use delegate methods or completion blocks.

Comment: What is `ViewDidLoad()`? The code in your question is not valid.

Comment: "But this doesn't work" is very vague. Please add more details of what doesn't work and what have you tried to make it work.

Comment: What is not working? and what is the timing of calling the myMethod function? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

To provide communication between two or multiple classes there are two method that are recommended.
1) Delegation
2) Notification

In your given code to implement delegation method we have to create protocol and delegate property in FacebookManager. And assign view controller as a delegate to FacebookManger

Example:

```
protocol FacebookManagerDelegate: class {
     func refreshData()
}

class FacebookManager  {
  var weak delegate:FacebookManagerDelegate?
  func myMethod() {
     delegate?.refreshData()
    }
}

class ViewController: FacebookManagerDelegate {
  ViewDidLoad() {
    FacebookManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self
  }

 func refreshData() {
  self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

But you are using singleton class therefore in future multiple class would be using this class and if you want to notify multiple classes use Notification method, which pretty easy to implement and should be use in singleton class

Post notification in FacebookManger whenever you want to notify:

```
 class FacebookManager  {
  func myMethod() {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationName, object: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController {
  ViewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(reloadData(_:)), name: NotificationName, object: nil)
  }
  deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }

 func reloadData(notification: NSNotification) {
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
   }
 }
```

Comment: You didn't mention the most convenient way: 3) Callbacks / completion blocks